# How can I pass arguments to a Perl 6 grammar?

Tags: grammar, raku

In [Edit distance: Ignore start/end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45256043/2766176), I offered a Perl 6 solution to a fuzzy fuzzy matching problem. I had a grammar like this (although maybe I've improved it after Edit #3):

```
grammar NString {
    regex n-chars { [<.ignore>* \w]**4 }
    regex ignore  { \s }
    }
```

The literal `4` itself was the length of the target string in the example. But the next problem might be some other length. So how can I tell the grammar how long I want that match to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the docs don't show an example or using the `$args` parameter, I found one in [S05-grammar/example.t in roast](https://github.com/perl6/roast/blob/master/S05-grammar/example.t).

Specify the arguments in `:args` and give the regex an appropriate signature. Inside the regex, access the arguments in a code block:

```
grammar NString {
    regex n-chars ($length) { [<.ignore>* \w]**{ $length } }
    regex ignore { \s }
    }

class NString::Actions {
    method n-chars ($/) {
        put "Found $/";
        }
    }

my $string = 'The quick, brown butterfly';

loop {
    state $from = 0;
    my $match = NString.subparse(
        $string,
        :rule('n-chars'),
        :actions(NString::Actions),
        :c($from++),
        :args( \(5) )
        );

    last unless ?$match;
    }
```

I'm still not sure about the rules for passing the arguments though. This doesn't work:

```
        :args( 5 )
```

I get:

> Too few positionals passed; expected 2 arguments but got 1

This works:

```
        :args( 5, )
```

But that's enough thinking about this for one night.

Comment: It's expecting to be passed a `Capture`, and if it doesn't get one then calls the `.Capture` coercer. A `List` will coerce to a `Capture` with the list elements as the positional arguments. An `Int` doesn't turn into anything useful (it falls back to the `Mu.Capture`, which takes public attributes and uses those as named parameters; an `Int` has no public attributes).

Comment: How do any of those turn into two arguments?

Comment: i expect that refers to the invocant, i.e. the "self" argument, as regexes in a class are methods.