# How can a Perl 6 rule pass arguments to another rule?

Tags: regex, grammar, raku

In [How can I pass arguments to a Perl 6 grammar?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45272338/2766176) I passed an argument to a rule as part of a submerse. I was wondering how I'd do that completely inside a grammar. Suppose I had something like:

```
grammar TryIt {
    rule TOP            { \d+ <stuff> }
    rule stuff ($count) { <[ \S A..Z ]>{$count} }
    }

my $match = TryIt.parse: "123 ABCD";
say $match;
```

How do I pass an argument from `TOP` to `stuff`? I didn't find any examples and various guesses about parens near stuff didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These forms both work:

```perl6
<stuff(...)>
```

```perl6
<stuff: ...>
```

Not sure where they're listed in the user documentation, but the *S05: Regexes and Rules* design document [has a section on them](https://design.perl6.org/S05.html#line_1493).

---

Note that inside a rule, backreferences like `$0` and `$/` are only guaranteed to be available after a sequence point, e.g the opening brace of a block. An empty block `{}` works.

Example:

```perl6
grammar TryIt {
    token TOP            { (\d+) \s {} <stuff($0)> .* }
    token stuff ($count) { <[ A..Z ]> ** {$count} }
}

say TryIt.subparse: "3 ABCDEFG";
```

Output:

```perl6
｢3 ABCDEFG｣
 0 => ｢3｣
 stuff => ｢ABC｣
```